# Giving Mesh thickness with additional requirements

Tags: modeling, uv, modifiers

I have some meshes that are parts of hallways with different crossings but all walls have no thickness.
For purposes of rendering it in a game I program they need thick walls (for avoiding artifacts with shadow mapping).

How can I achieve this thickness with Blender? My three conditions are

1. No self intersections: I know about the solidify-modifier but the angles of my mesh make it so, that the new thickness intersects with itself which is not ideal (z-fighting).
2. UV-coordinates of all pre-existing vertices have to stay the same. We have a cool looking texture and the texture-mapping has to stay the same.
3. Stay tileable: The meshes get positioned next to each other in order to form a maze. This has to be possible with the thick meshes.

The outward appearance of the mesh is not important since they are only seen from the inside. Additional I should be able to do this within a day for round about 10 meshes.

Comment: Is this question answered, or is more information needed? Please notify if you need more help.

Comment: Had no time to really try it out. On a small glace it seemed to work. I will accept the answer

Comment: Okay, thanks. Make sure to tell me if you need more help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use a modifier in this case. You will probably have to do it manually.

- *Go* into **edit** mode <kbd>tab</kbd>
- *select* **all** <kbd>a</kbd>
- **extrude** <kbd>e</kbd>
- **scale** <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, (which will *only* scale on **x** and **z**.)

Now, if there are faces which are on top of each other (in the same place), you can try any of these options;

1. <kbd>s</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to scale along *y*.
2. Change pivot point to *individual origins*, then scale on y.
3. Simply adjust it *manually*.

It's hard to say what you should do, because I haven't seen the mesh, but this should help. Keep in mind, that I am assuming facing down your tunnel is the *y* axis. When scaling, you want to exclude the axis you are looking down, so that it only gets wider, not longer.

I hope this helped, please comment with any questions.